# Exclude list of Vms from script deleting snapshots in vmware

Tags: powercli

I have a `powercli` script which is scheduled to delete the `VMs` older than X days, recently we got a list of `VMs` which are supposed to be excluded from the snapshot deletion as these are critical Snapshots.
How do I introduce the parameter exclude `VM` in my script to compare the `VMS` with a snapshot in Vcenter to the list I provide and list and delete only `VMS` which meets the criteria of not older than X days and not part of the Exclude `VM` list.

I am relatively new and using below code to fetch snapshots older than 10 Days and delete them.

```
# vCenter Server configuration
   $vcenter = "Vcenter Name"
$vcenteruser = "Domain\Userid"
$vcenterpw = "Password"

#Connect to the vCenter server defined above. Ignore certificate errors
Connect to vcenter Server connect-viserver $vcenter -User $vcenteruser -Password $vcenterpw"


Add-PSSnapin VMware.VimAutomation.Core -ErrorAction 'SilentlyContinue'
Clear-Host
$old_snapshots = Get-VM | Get-Snapshot |? { ([DateTime]::Now - $_.Created).TotalDays -gt 7 } | Remove-Snapshot: $old_snapshots | Remove-Snapshot -RunAsync -Confirm:$false
```

I need to figure out what if i have a list of 'vms' having snapshots older than 10 days which shouldn't be deleted. I want to exclude those 'Vms' but i am not sure how to do that.

So I tried Using the logic by @ I.T Delinquent . I put a value in '$VmToIgnore' and compare it with the list of VMs received in 'Get-Vm'. If it is true do nothing, If it s false, get snapshot and other attribute of that VM and export it to CSV.

```
$vmsToIgnore ="Vm1"
$e = Get-VM
    Foreach-Object {
    if ($vmsToIgnore -Contains $_.Name){  
        #Do nothing as VM name is in the vmsToIgnore list
    }else{

          $f = $e |get-Snapshot| Select-object 
         vm,VMId,name,Description,SizeGB,created

         $f| Export-Csv -Path "\\%path%\snapshot.csv"
    }
}
```

This is still returning list of all 'VM' Snapshots including the one n '$VMToIgnore'.

I must be making some mistake here as it should not print the '$VmToIgnore' in Excel.

Comment: Could you provide something that you have already tried and the specific issues you are experiencing?

Comment: I have updated my  question with the code I am using. I am trying to find a way to exclude few 'Vm' snapshots from this auto delete 'VM' Snapshot script. But I am not sure how to do that.

Comment: What's the format of the list you received? TXT? CSV? Something else?
Is the list going to be changing often or will it be relatively static?

Comment: @TheSinghSyndrome I have updated my answer. Please review :)

Comment: Thank you so much @ I.T Delinquent. This is working as I needed. :)

Answer (score 0):

Could you build upon something like this:

```
$vmsToIgnore = "VM1","VM2"

$old_Snapshots = Get-VM | Foreach-Object {
    if ($vmsToIgnore -Contains $_.Name){  
        #Do nothing as VM name is in the vmsToIgnore list
    }else{
        #Perform tasks as vm isn't in vmsToIgnore list
    }
}
```

I'm not really sure what Get-VM will return so please you will likely have to edit my example. Here is the basis of it though assuming that Get-VM returns a nice list of VMs:

```
$vmsToIgnore = "VM1","VM2"
$outputFromGetVM = "VM1","VM1.2","VM2","VM3"

foreach ($vm in $outputFromGetVM){
    if ($vmsToIgnore -contains $vm){
        Write-Host "Ignoring"
    }else{
        Write-Host "performing"
    }
}
```

Let me know if you have any questions

**UPDATE**

I think this could be used:

```
$vmsToIgnore = "Vm1"

Get-VM | ForEach-Object {
    if ($vmsToIgnore -contains $_.Name){
        #Do nothing as VM name is in the vmsToIgnore list
    }else{
        Get-Snapshot $_ | Select-Object vm, VmId, Name, Description, SizeGB, Created | Export-Csv -Path "\\path\to\file.csv"
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried to use the logic you provided.Here 'Get-VM' gets list of all the 'VMs' in vcenter. Then according to your logic it is compared with $VMsToIgnore . If it matches, do nothing.If they do not match fetch snapshot Details of that 'VM' and export it to CSV.

I am not using delete snapshot command as t is just for testng. So I have modified script to get only 'VM' snapshot details .

Comment: '$vmsToIgnore ="Vm1"
$e = Get-VM
    Foreach-Object {
    if ($vmsToIgnore -Contains $_.Name){  
        #Do nothing as VM name is in the vmsToIgnore list
    }else{

          $f = $e |get-Snapshot| Select-object vm,VMId,name,Description,SizeGB,created
        
       $f| Export-Csv -Path "\\%path%\snapshot.csv"
    }
}'

Comment: @TheSinghSyndrome Could you update your question with this information? Also, I don't really understand the purpose of your comments. Is something broken with my answer?

Comment: I have updated the question again.  am sorry I am new  here , hence still learning .

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you have the VM names as a list already in which case exclude them

$list = Get-VM | where {"name" -ne "mypreciousvm"}

You will need to play with -notmatch or -notcontains I can't remember which one you will need. Then pass the exclusion list below.

$old_snapshots = Get-VM -name $list | Get-Snapshot |? { ([DateTime]::Now - $_.Created).TotalDays -gt 7 } | Remove-Snapshot: $old_snapshots | Remove-Snapshot -RunAsync -Confirm:$false

If Vms come and go a lot then try to do it in one go otherwise you may get an error as you reget the vm name

$old_snapshots = Get-VM | where {$*.name -notcontains $list}| Get-Snapshot |? { ([DateTime]::Now - $*.Created).TotalDays -gt 7 } | Remove-Snapshot: $old_snapshots | Remove-Snapshot -RunAsync -Confirm:$false

Answer (score 0):

***Delete Snapshots that are older than 3 days***

```
Get-VM | Get-Snapshot | ? {$_.created -lt (Get-Date).AddDays(-3)} | Remove-Snapshot -Confirm:$false -RunAsync
```

Comment: Because you are only showing code, it is not clear how this answer is different from the others, how the shown code works and why it is supposed to solve the problem as described in the question at the top of this page. Please [edit] according to the info here [answer]. And when you have time, please do take the highly recommended [tour].

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.